# How to RUN rosdep init and update in Dockerfile

Tags: rosdep, docker, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's the correct way of running `sudo rosdep init` followed by `rosdep update` in a Dockerfile?

Looking at OSRF's [indigo-ros-core](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/master/ros/indigo/indigo-ros-core/Dockerfile) Dockerfile, there's a simple:

```
RUN rosdep init \
    && rosdep update
```

However, running `rosdep update` like that in my own Dockerfile results in a warning, since it was essentially run with `sudo`. In turn, this results in `rosdep install` not finding dependencies later on.

So, since I'll be running this Docker image on a Raspberry Pi 3, I've been trying the [Docker-raspbian-ros-indigo](https://github.com/PabloGN/Docker-raspbian-ros-indigo/blob/master/Dockerfile) Dockerfile, which sets up a new user, `pi`, and then runs the `rosdep` commands as that user (see link for details).

```
USER pi
RUN sudo rosdep init
RUN rosdep update
```

But trying to build my Dockerfile like that gives me the following error message:

```
Step 12 : RUN sudo rosdep init
---> Running in d10888b83a25
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
```

I also tried the trick from [osblinnikov/ros-docker](https://github.com/osblinnikov/ros-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile). In a nutshell:

```
RUN adduser --gecos "ROS User" --disabled-password ros
RUN usermod -a -G dialout ros
USER ros
RUN HOME=/home/ros rosdep update
# ...
RUN rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO -y
```

However, the `rosdep install` commands fails with:

```
Step 20 : RUN rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO -y
 ---> Running in 3be8cdf3c72a
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python-mock] failed
executing command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python-mock]
The command '/bin/sh -c rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO -y' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Update: This last error was resolved by:

- letting the `ros` user execute commands as sudo without password (`ros ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`)
- and also adding `RUN sudo apt-get update` before `rosdep install` in order to update the package lists

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241112/how-to-run-rosdep-init-and-update-in-dockerfile/) by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1788 on 2016-08-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're doing all of this in the Dockerfile it's recommended to run everything as root.

There's no point in changing the user to `pi` then using `sudo` to run the command with super user privlages. You only want to drop into the `pi` user shortly before you finish the Dockerfile and provide the entrypoint.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-08-04**:
Thanks for the quick reply Tully. So, I guess it's OK to ignore `Warning: running 'rosdep update' as root is not recommended.` in a Dockerfile? Looks like it worked so no complaints here :-)

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2016-08-04**:
If you run rosdep update as root only root will have access to the database. This is typically a problem if people run `sudo rosdep update` then try to run `rosdep install` at which time root has the db, but the USER does not. In this case you are going to run rosdep install as root. So it's fine.